# Github switch master repository

Tags: git

I've created a new account at github for a company, and I cloned my own repository to that account.

However, I would like the repository in the company account to be the master (so my account can create pull request to the company and not vice versa).

How do I make that happen?

I was thinking about deleting my own repository and then clone the company accounts. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer ownership of a repository in the repo admin options. I have never used this function, but it looks like you need admin rights in an organization to be able to transfer the repo to the organization's account. Alternatively you can ask support to transfer the repo to another user.

[image]